# Solr and Zookeeper - 3 Z- Nodes . which node should i use as API to may searh request

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I've been working on a system where they use SolrCloud, which entails a Zookeeper ensemble that helps

> "manage the overall structure so that both indexing and search
> requests can be routed properly"

I have 3 Z-Nodes. which node should I use as API for search request. and what if it down? how Zookeeper will be able to change IP in my code to another Z-node?

I know it dosen't work like that ! but am trying  to figure it out.

Comment: you have it as three node..one would be the leader and other will be the follower...if the leader goes down..the one of the follower becomes leader as serves the request...https://medium.com/@sarkaramrit2/setting-up-solr-cloud-6-3-0-with-zookeeper-3-4-6-867b96ec4272

Comment: So follower can be as a leader elected, but what about the ip adress from the leader, which I am using to query search (rest api) the OP will not change according to the new leader? What am missing here?

Comment: you will be defining the zkHostString = "SERVERNAME:PORT,SERVERNAME:PORT,SERVERNAME:PORT"

Comment: which language are you using for indexing and quering

Comment: ...somthing like localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183

Comment: I am going to use Java with some http client for querying..

Comment: It's like doing get request with postman

Comment: ok then you build the connection using the below code...CloudSolrClient solrClient; String zkHostString = "SERVERNAME:8997,SERVERNAME:8998,SERVERNAME:8999"; 
        if(solrClient == null){
            solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHostString).build();
        }
        return solrClient;

Comment: I think am starting getting sense of it !

Comment: So am not connecting directly to solr, am connecting to zookeeper group of node , which it will return an up and running leader node.... thanks alot

Comment: Do you know where to find a good example using solr and zookeeper ensemble, running with docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using solr cloud with zookeeper ensemble and connecting it using Java.

You can get the connection as below with java code.

```
CloudSolrClient solrClient;
     
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CloudSolrClient createConnection(){
        //You need to replace SERVERNAME with the server on which the zookeeper is running
        String zkHostString = "SERVERNAME:PORT,SERVERNAME:PORT,SERVERNAME:PORT"; 
        if(solrClient == null){
            solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHostString).build();
        }
        return solrClient;
    }
```

Here you need pass all the zookeeper nodes which are running for managing your solr servers. You can also use springboot for your application where in you can configure the zk-host as part of the application.properties.

Comment: @kaleb: If it answers your question, Please accept the answer.